# Starting an EC2 instance via AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am trying to create a lambda function on AWS to start and stop an EC2 instance, but it's giving the following error

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the StartInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

What are the steps which should I take to stop this error? I am not a developer, just trying to run some ML model via EC2. I read something on creating an IAM role, which I did with full EC2 access, but I am not sure how to use the same in the lambda function. Can anyone guide me on the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When creating an AWS Lambda function, you assign an **IAM Role** to the function.

When the function makes an AWS API call, it uses the permissions provided in the IAM Role to call other AWS services.

Therefore, you should:

- Create an IAM Role with sufficient permissions for the Lambda function to work (but preferably not *too much* permission, since it could create security holes)
- Assign the IAM Role to the Lambda function

Your function would need, at minimum, the `ec2:StartInstances` permission. It's likely that it will need other permissions too, depending upon the settings used when launching an instance.